# Warning "An update inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)" that happens in very strange circumstances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

When writing a new test in my React-based project I've encountered a warning `An update to Activities inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)`. Normally, I have dealt with this kind of warning multiple times, but this time it happens in a very strange circumstances that I don't understand.

I've managed to shrink my project to a single component and a single test case that shows this behavior.

## The code

The below files (along with `package.json` and some other files) of the shrinked-down project can be also found [in this repository](https://github.com/Xaaq/strange-behavior/tree/main).

**jest.setup.tsx**

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";

export const user = userEvent.setup({advanceTimers: jest.advanceTimersByTime})

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
})
afterEach(() => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()
    jest.useRealTimers()
})


const someRandomVariable = render
```

**activities.tsx** (file with component and test)

```
import {user} from "../../jest.setup"
import {act, render, screen, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react"
import React, {useState} from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import useSWR from "swr";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";


export default function Activities() {
    const {data, mutate, error} = useSWR(
        `http://localhost:8000/activity`,
        url => axios<{ name: string }>({method: "GET", url})
            .then(r => r.data)
            .then(data => data)
            .then(data => data)
            .then(data => data)
            .then(data => data)
            // .then(data => data)
    )
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")


    if (data === undefined)
        return <div>loading</div>

    return <>
        {message}
        data name: {data.name}
        <button
            onClick={async () => {
                // here would be a function that makes a backend call to change the name, but let's omit it
                await mutate(_ => ({name: "second name"}))
                setMessage("name changed")
            }}
        >
            change activity name
        </button>
    </>
}

export const axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios)

test("pressing button", async () => {
    // given
    axiosMock.onGet(`http://localhost:8000/activity`).reply(200, {name: "first name"})

    render(<Activities/>)
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/change activity name/i)).toBeInTheDocument())
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/data name: first name/i)).toBeInTheDocument())

    // when
    // this mock is here to make sure SWR won't be able to fetch data - instead, we will depend on the effect of using `mutate` function
    axiosMock.onGet(`http://localhost:8000/activity`).reply(500, {})
    await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: /change activity name/i}))

    // then
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/name changed/i)).toBeInTheDocument())
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/data name: second name/i)).toBeInTheDocument())
})
```

## What to do to reproduce the problem?

Let's follow the steps:

1. Run the test - it passes and there is no warning.
2. Comment-out the `const someRandomVariable = render` line in `jest.setup.tsx` - **running the test now shows the warning**.
3. Let's revert the above line back so the test starts working properly again.
4. Un-comment the `// .then(data => data)` line - **now running the test will show the warning**.
5. Let's add another `.then(data => data)` statement under line 18 - **the warning during test magically disappears**.
6. Revert the above line, so the test shows warning again.
7. Remove the `error` from the line `const {data, mutate, error} = useSWR(` - **the warning disappears again**

As you see there are many arbitrary changes we can do to make test spit out the warning or to silence the warning.

## So my question is....

Why is the warning happening?